# Which version of Spider-Man does Stan Lee like the best?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, stan-lee

There are versions of Spider-Man in the Spider-Man Trilogy, The Amazing Spider-Man, and in Captain America: Civil War.

Which movie Spider-Man does the creator of Spider-Man (Stan Lee) consider to be the version *most close to his original vision*?

Comment: I’m just going to blow your mind here: there are also different versions of Batman!

Comment: There’s some discussion of why there are different movie versions of Spider-Man in these questions: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55641, and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46513.

Comment: @kvchivukula - I've done a pretty chunky edit on your question. If you think I've gone too far, feel free to use the [edit button](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/133388/edit) to roll it back to the earlier version.

Comment: There are considerably more versions of Spider-Man than just these three examples. You've missed out two Made-for-TV films and several TV series; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_film

Comment: There are even different Spider Man versions in the comics. So to be precise you would need to ask which comic version Lee likes most and then if the movie adaptation of that version was to his liking

Comment: In-universe, he prefers Spider-Man.

Comment: I actually sought the answer for which is the most appropriate one, but any how there are many potrayals of spiderman. I should assume that one can play with characters in comics.Your edit is good too @Valorum

Comment: @kvchivukula: “I actually sought the answer for which is the most appropriate one”. You might need to clarify what you mean by “appropriate”.

Comment: @kvchivukula - I should warn you that in its original form, your question was liable to be closed as too broad.

Comment: @Paul D.Waite 'The appropriate one' means which spiderman portrayal is generally obeyed by the creators. I think that its reasonable there should not be too many confusing versions of same character.

Comment: @Valorum thanks for your edit.I admit that my original question seemed broad.I'll try to narrow next time when I come up with one.

Comment: @kvchivukula: you mean approved by the original creators? Gotcha. “I think that its reasonable there should not be too many confusing versions of same character.” Heh! I’m not sure if comics is the right entertainment medium for you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [this article](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2016/06/10/stan-lee-reveals-his-favorite-comic-book-movie), Stan Lee says that his favourite comic book movie, not even just his favourite Spider-Man movie, is the original Spider-Man, in which Spidey is played by Tobey Maguire.

> "*I think my favorite comic book movie was the first one that was such
>   a hit, the first Spider-Man,*" Lee said in reply to a fan on Facebook,
>   going on to add that "*everything else seemed easy*" for the comic book
>   movies that followed once that film was made.

Having said that, Spider-Man and The Amazing Spider-Man are both movies made by Sony and have no bearing on the Marvel Cinematic Universe. The ONLY Spider-Man, and therefore the most "correct" Spider-Man, is the one in Civil War, as far as the MCU is concerned.